# Can you make a responsive viewbox?

Tags: html, svg, resolution, viewbox, sizing

If you have a view box set too large, the page will scroll.  Is there a way to make a view box fit the size of any given browser? For example, I am on a 1600 x 1900 browser right now with this view box:

```
<svg viewBox="-300 0 1920 995">
```

and my page scrolls.  I made the webpage on a 1080p monitor originally and the page did not scroll.

Answer (score 1):

You've kind of got things the wrong way round.  The `viewBox` is what you use to make SVGs responsive.  It tells the browser how to scale the contents of your SVG to fit the parent. 
 The `width` and `height` attributes are what sets the size of the SVG.

What you need to do is restrict the size of the SVG to your window. Then the `viewBox` will let you size the content to fit.

For example:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">

  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="rebeccapurple"/>
  
</svg>
```

In this example. I've forced the `<body>` to match the window size. Then made the SVG fill that.

Make the example full screen.  Then try enlarging and shrinking the window. Make it narrow or wide.  The circle will automatically resize so it fits in the window.

Comment: I've got SVG elements that scale with the page within the viewbox stated in the post..None of them are larger than the page though.  Why is my page scrolling?

Comment: The parent SVG element needs to scale with the page.

Comment: @ChristianCaraballo There could be several reasons.  Please provide a [mcve] so we can see what you are actually doing.